# Categorizing non-ID categories PHP loop

Tags: php, loops, content-type

On my project there're various search results of different content-types. For unimportant reasons, not all content-types carry a unique ID. However, I tried to write this loop that will detect IDless content-types, and will give them a unique ID.

Basically, the results look like this:

- Category ID 3
- Category ID 3
- Category ID 4
- NON-ID Category 1
- NON-ID Category 2

[...]

I tried this:

```
$current = $result->section;                        
// if there's a category ID -- use it
if ($current != null) echo $result->sectionid;
    else
    // if this is the first IDless category -- initialize. this happens once.
    if ($virginity == true) {
        $store = $current;
        $virginity = false;                             
        }
// if initialized and current category string is the same as stored category string -- print it
if (($virginity == 0) && ($store = $current)) {
    echo $defaultID;
    }
// if initialized and current category string is different from the stored category string -- set new default category +1 and print it
if (($virginity == false) && ($store != $current)) {
    $defaultID = $defaultID++;
    echo $defaultID;
    $store = $current;
    }
```

Can you see where I'm going here?
Trying to give each new category that comes up in the search results a unique ID, on the next loop session - check if the category string is same as the previous one, if so -- use the same ID, else -- bump ID by 1, print the new ID and store a new category.

However: This doesn't work properly.

Why?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is a little tough to read, but a big red flag I see is this block:

```
//You have  a single equals sign here v
if (($virginity == 0) && ($store = $current)) 
{
    echo $defaultID;
}
```

That means that as long as `$virginity==0`, that line will always be run, and `$store` will always equal `$current`.

By the way, I'm going to recommend some reformatting and readability suggestions. Take them or leave them , though, it's just my opinion.

$current = $result->section;

if ($current != null) 
 {//if one of the results has brackets, put brackets on both
  echo $result->sectionid;
 }
 else if ($virginity == true) 
 {// if this is the first IDless category -- initialize. this happens once.
  $store = $current;
  $virginity = false;
 }

```
//you're setting $virginity=false or true, so doing !$virginity makes sense
// if it was actually a number, then comparing to 0 is better
// also, use parentheses only where really needed, otherwise it's just clutter
if (!$virginity && $store == $current) 
{
    echo $defaultID;
}
```

if (!$virginity && $store != $current) 
 {// if initialized and current category string is different from the stored category string -- set new default category +1 and print it
  $defaultID = $defaultID++;
  echo $defaultID;
  $store = $current;
 }